# Get Promotion line item value with SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm attempting to use SuiteScript to get an array of the values in the "Promotions" sublist (SuitePromotions is turned on).  The nlapiGetLineItemField is returning a strange output "com.netledger.app.common.scripting.version1.nlobjFieldImplV1@1e874f2e" rather than the internal ID or name of the promotion.  How do I access the sublist data in this object?  Here's my code:

```
            //get the promotions used on the transaction
        var transPromos = [];
        var promoCount = nlapiGetLineItemCount('promotions');
        for (var promoNum = 1; promoNum <= promoCount; promoNum++){
        var promoName = nlapiGetLineItemField('promotions', 'promocode', promoNum);
            transPromos.push(promoName);
        }
       nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'transPromos', transPromos);
```

And then later...

```
       for (var k = 0; k < transPromos.length; k++){    
       nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'transpromo' + k.toString(), transPromos[k]);
       }
```

Log shows:

> transPromos:  com.netledger.app.common.scripting.version1.nlobjFieldImplV1@592bd210
>   transpromo0:  com.netledger.app.common.scripting.version1.nlobjFieldImplV1@592bd210

I want it to print the internal ID or the name of the promotion. What am I missing here?  Why does it show this strange code instead of the internal ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it. I used nlapiGetLineItemText() instead of nlapiGetLineItemField() to get the name of the promotion.

Comment: nlapiGetLineItemValue also works. nlapiGetLineItemField is for getting the field type.